# How to partition and typecast a List in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, casting, partitioning

In Kotlin I can:

```
val (specificMembers, regularMembers) = members.partition {it is SpecificMember}
```

However to my knowledge I can not do something like:

```
val (specificMembers as List<SpecificMember>, regularMembers) = members.partition {it is SpecificMember}
```

My question would be - is there's an idiomatic way to partition iterable by class and typecast it those partitioned parts if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `partition` function will return a `Pair<List<T>, List<T>>` with `T` being the generic type of your `Iterable`. You can transform the partitioned values again using e.g. `let`:

```
val (specificMembers, regularMembers) = lists
    .partition { it is SpecificMember }
    .let { Pair(it.first as List<SpecificMember>, it.second) }
```

Comment: is 'a` to `b` and idiomatic way to create a Pair though?

Comment: However you prefer. The `to` function is one of the few standard infix functions available and a frequently used one

Comment: Since this is not really important, I changed it to the actual constructor

Comment: but that introduces an unchecked cast :(

Answer (score 6):

If you require that functionality more often, you may just reimplement the actual [`partition`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html#partition) according to your needs, e.g.:

```
inline fun <reified U : T, T> Iterable<T>.partitionByType(): Pair<List<U>, List<T>> {
  val first = ArrayList<U>()
  val second = ArrayList<T>()
  for (element in this) {
    if (element is U) first.add(element)
    else second.add(element)
  }
  return Pair(first, second)
}
```

with a usage similar as to follows:

```
val (specificMembers, regularMembers) = members.partitionByType<SpecificMember, Member>()
// where specificMembers : List<SpecificMember>
// and regularMembers : List<Member> for this example
```

Note that this way you can also set the second type to a more generic one. I leave that up to you whether this makes sense. At least this way an [unchecked cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unchecked-casts) isn't necessary.

The alternative is also shown by Simon with the [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html)-usage. You can also directly cast the result of [`partition`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html#partition) (without `let` and another `Pair`) to whatever fits, e.g.:

```
val (specificMembers, regularMembers) = members.partition {it is SpecificMember} as Pair<List<SpecificMember>, List<Member>>
```