# Kotlin extension function with generic types dependant on the receiver type parameter (without specifying it explicitly)

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-extension

Sometimes I want to have an extension function on a generic type, whose parameter or return value is a subtype of the given type parameter, but without having to specify that actual type parameter. (maybe, if it isn't clear, the code will clarify it better?)

Using the signature of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56326038/6202869):

```
inline fun <reified U : T, T> Iterable<T>.partitionByType(): Pair<List<U>, List<T>>
```

It forces me to use it as follows:

```
val list : List<SomeType>
list.partitionByType<InterestedType, SomeType>()
```

However, what I rather want to write is the following:

```
list.partitionByType<InterestedType>()
```

Where `InterestedType` is a subtype of the type parameter of the list, i.e. `SomeType`. Both solutions above should then give me `Pair<List<InterestedType>, List<SomeType>>` as a return value.

This however isn't really possible. The best that comes to my mind is a signature similar as to follows:

```
 inline fun <reified U : Any> Iterable<Any>.partitionByType(): Pair<List<U>, List<Any>>
```

But then we lose the actual type `T`/`SomeType` which was known otherwise. An unchecked cast is still possible on the caller side, but that's not what I am after.

So my question is: is this somehow possible? Having something like `U : T` in place, without specifying the `T`? Or is there anything planned in this regard (KEEP or Kotlin issue available)?

For me it sounds like a reasonable feature, at least as long as it is applied on an extension function only. If it's not, what would be the problems of this that I am probably just overlooking/ignoring at the moment?
What I am not really looking for is a workaround (like having an intermediate type), but it may be worth it to have it as answer as well.

The more I think of it. Wouldn't it be more correct, if extension functions on generic types would be declared as follows?

```
fun SomeType<T>.extended()
```

instead of

```
fun <T> SomeType<T>.extended()
```

Because: if I were under control of `SomeType<T>` and would add that function there, I wouldn't need any generic type information to declare it, e.g. the following would suffice then:

```
fun extended()
```

Same regarding functions with own generic types, e.g.:

```
fun <U : T> extended2()
```

Adding that as extension function now forces one to add that `T`-generic type, although the type on which we would like to apply it, is clearly `SomeType<T>`:

```
fun <T, U: T> SomeType<T>.extended2()
```

Answer (score 1):

Attention: this is a self-answer only for the "intermediate type"-solution-part. I am still looking for an answer if it can be solved without such a workaround or if there are plans to support it.

Example of an intermediate type to solve that issue could look as follows:

```
class PartitionType<T>

inline fun <reified T> type() = PartitionType<T>()
inline fun <reified U : T, T> Iterable<T>.partitionBy(type: PartitionType<U> = type()): Pair<List<U>, List<T>> {
    val first = ArrayList<U>()
    val second = ArrayList<T>()
    for (element in this) {
        if (element is U) first.add(element)
        else second.add(element)
    }
    return Pair(first, second)
}
```

This way one can write:

```
list.partitionBy(type<InterestedType>())
```

which will result in the `Pair<List<InterestedType>, List<SomeType>>`-return value, but requires to add that type that will not be used anyhow (except indirectly; an `inline class` may make sense here, but ... what should the parameter be then?).

The key here is to just pass the interested type(s) as parameter instead of specifying it as a requested generic type (`partitionBy<InterestedType, SomeType>()` would still work (or more correctly: would still be needed)).

Maybe I used the wrong words and that's why I couldn't find anything suitable yet. Or maybe it's just something I want to have and no one else? At least for me it sounds as if it could/should work.

Another variant is to explicitly specify all the extension functions on types that are known already, but then we need to be aware of platform clashes, e.g.:

```
@JvmName("partitionSomeTypeByType") // only needed if we require more partitionByType-functions with differing generic type parameters
inline fun <reified U : SomeType> Iterable<SomeType>.partitionByType() = partitionBy<U, SomeType>()
```

But again only a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Another not nearly elegant solution, which may be considered even worse than passing a `type<T>()` as it isn't universal and requires boilerplate for each such a function, is to return a wrapper object (that is similarly meaningless).

However, with the use of `inline` classes, it can be implemented without any runtime overhead, so I'll post it here anyway:

```
fun main() {
    println(listOf<Number>(1, 2.0, 3f).doPartition.byType<Int>())
}

inline class PartitionByTypeWrapper<T>(val list: List<T>) {
    inline fun <reified U : T> byType(): Pair<List<U>, List<T>> {
        val (us, ts) = list.partition { it is U }
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return us as List<U> to ts
    }
}

inline val <T> List<T>.doPartition get() = PartitionByTypeWrapper(this)
```

Comment: hmm... the `inline class` should probably also be applied for my `PartitionType`-class... (but what should the parameter be then... `KClass<T>` and `T: Any`? some other wrapper type just to deliver the generic type? don't know... I will skip it for the moment :-))